s3 File is not being uploaded from Baseten server
Im using boto3 for uploading files to s3 bucket. I have this script hosted in Baseten for GPU which will generate audio file and upload that to s3 bucket. For some reason, which im not understanding it throws an error whenever the code for uploading the file runs.
Below is the code im using
s3_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=self._secrets["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"],aws_secret_access_key=self._secrets["AWS_SECRET_KEY"])
self.s3_client = s3_session.client('s3',region_name='us-east-1')
cors_configuration = {
'CORSRules': [{
'AllowedHeaders': ['Authorization'],
'AllowedMethods': ['GET', 'PUT'],
'AllowedOrigins': ['*'],
'ExposeHeaders': ['ETag', 'x-amz-request-id'],
'MaxAgeSeconds': 3000
}]
}
self.s3_client.put_bucket_cors(Bucket=self.bucket_name,CORSConfiguration=cors_configuration)
self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=f'{filename}.mp3', Body=wav)

I thought it was some configuration  issue so i tried to see if this will run on ec2 instance it is working it also works on my local computer and also the docker container im running on my local machine
Below is the error im getting

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 495, in send
raise ProxyConnectionError(
botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://127.0.0.1:3128"`

I would like to know if im missing something. Any insight on this is appreciated 

Have you configured a proxy in boto3? If you're not sure, check in your ~/.aws/config file.

Yes as u stated proxy is not setup in the file. Where can i get these proxy url do i need to set these up. Again thank you for the insight

@JohnRotenstein The issue was with baseTen service which i was using which was somehow causing this error. Have a good day
